# File upload option to take image from camera or select from galler not working for web app in mozilla firefox

Tags: php, firefox, file-upload, web-applications

In my web app i have to allow user to select file from the gallery or file manager OR take a picture using the camera.

It is working in chrome and safari but it is not working in mozilla firefox.

```
<div class="form-group col-12">
  <label for="file-upload-car-insurance" class="custom-file-upload">
    <span>Click To Upload Copy Of Insurance Policy </span>
    <img src="images/license-icon.svg" class="ic_icons" />
  </label>
  <input
    id="file-upload-car-insurance"
    name="car_accident_copy_of_insurance_policy"
    type="file"
    style="display: none"
  />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with Firefox, am having exactly the same issue. Must be recent as we have used this process for a long time.